# Cannot retrieve Json from my api in android studios but can only retrieve in string

Tags: android, spring-boot, api, android-studio

I have made an api using Spring boot and I tested the endpoints using postman and it is working fine.
When I try to access the data from the android studio, it does not return anything if the object is JsonObject type. If it is String object type then it works. I want to work on json object instead.

The following code works when requested as string and the textView changes to the retrieved object.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://finalspringtutorial-env.eba-tbg7yt8b.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/soccerplayers";
// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        textView.setText("Response is: "+ response);
                        Log.i("stringresponse", response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                textView.setText("That didn't work!");
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);

        }    
}
```

It does not work when data is retrieved as JsonObject like below and the textView does not change.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="http://finalspringtutorial-env.eba-tbg7yt8b.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/soccerplayers";

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    textView.setText(response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

I think it has to do with my api also because when I change the url to a pulic api like https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity then I do get the response body as json and is displayed on the view. My api which is hosted on aws works perfectly on postman but I wonder why it is not working when used through android studios.

Comment: Is any error in onErrorResponse ?

Comment: JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
        (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>()
May be you need to use this. Instead of JSONObject use JSONArray.

Comment: @SyedHamzaHassan, you were right. I printed the stacktrace. I had to use `        JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {` because my api returned an array first and then objects inside the array.